# how PaymentSplitter function really work?

Tags: solidity

I came across this function inside a smart contract that releases the shares between the team.

My question is :

Is it important to wait until all NFTs are minted and then release the payment for everyone? or it doesn't matter if the release would be in the beginning or in the end.

Is this function secure to implement?

```
// Release the payment based on the percentage
    function releaseAll() external onlyOwner {
        for(uint i = 0; i < teamLength; i++) {
            release(payable(payee(i)));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i tested it before, the contract keeps track of each token (eth) entrance. so if you have minted 500 of 1000 nfts you can withdraw your share until that point. so if you mint another 300 your share is with those 300 minted because you already withdraw your share of the 500 before. If another wallet hasn't withdraw since the beginning it will withdraw its share from the 800 minted.